# How To Get Bootstrap 4 Page To Fit Into Actual Mobile Display?

Tags: html, css, mobile, bootstrap-4

I'm developing https://contentbase.co. The frontpage (as it is at the time of writing) has been developed/tested with Chrome's dev console's device toolbar. The correct viewport is set and Bootstrap's column system has been utilized to make stuff stack.

All the elements stack correctly down to a very narrow width, as long as I retrieve the page with a desktop user agent string (which dev console does). I just found out that actual mobile devices will send along a mobile user agent string by default, and this changes how the page renders.

On dev console, it shows fine at 1080px wide. On an actual mobile device 1080px wide, it makes the elements and the fonts much larger. The content becomes broader than the screen. This is the error that Google search console gives me. And rightly so, because I am able to scroll horizontally now (big no no).

When I tell my smartphone's browser to request the desktop version of the site, it shows just fine... because it sends along a desktop user agent string.

I figured I'd need some reset css. So I copy pasted [webkit's user agent stylesheet](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css), which is used in Chrome desktop, into the css, hoping to override the user agent stylesheet offered by Chrome mobile. This was no panacea, unfortunately.

The biggest problem with this problem, is that I'm unsure how best to continuously test it while developing. I have to visit it with an actual smartphone, so debugging on localhost seems out of the question.

So I have to publish the problematic html/css to a live domain somewhere, which I can visit with my smartphone, then debug and reload with smartphone. But the problem with Chrome mobile is that there's no element inspector like I've got on Chrome desktop. That makes debugging the issue harder.

These circumstances make for quite a challenge in finding the issue, let alone fixing it.

I can't imagine I'm the first to run into this. What's the best way for developing/debugging/testing Bootstrap pages on actual mobile devices?

And what can I best do to ensure the mobile version of my site (retrieved with mobile user agent string) shows the same as the desktop version of my site (retrieved with desktop user agent string)?

Is this a known problem and is there a known, best-practice fix?

**Update:**

I've published some test files that I can access with my smartphone. I'm also outputting the container div's width in the page. Turns out my smartphone is displaying it at 330px wide. Previously, I thought it was displaying pages at its native resolution of 1080px width. At that very same 330px width, my dev console's device emulator is displaying the exact same issue. So now I can at least have a user friendly debugging experience.

Comment: It sounds like you're missing the `viewport META` tag. That will ensure your website displays as expected on mobile devices. As far as styling for mobile is concerned, you're looking for media queries. Though if you're using Bootstrap 4, it has them built-in.

Comment: As described, the viewport is set (as well as the DOCTYPE for anyone who's wondering). It's also in the source of the linked site. It works well when requested with desktop user agent. I know about media queries. What I don't know is why fonts and other elements are made bigger on a 1080px mobile display (no way to debug that I know of) than they are on a desktop display at 1080px. No wonder they don't fit if they're too big.

Comment: Mobile devices don't render sites at their native resolution, this has been the case since the release of the first iphone more than 10 years ago. That's why we can have different breakpoints for mobile and desktop.

Comment: Could be that that's been the case for 10 years. I never ran into it until now. But I found the solution, so I'll just go ahead and answer my own question so that other people can learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I wasn't aware that mobile devices don't render sites at their native resolution. My phone's display spec is 1080px wide, but it displays sites at a 330px width.

This caused some confusion. But once I learned that this was the problem, I was able to reproduce the problem in Chrome's dev console.

In my case, the problem was caused by some hardcoded 150px paddings. I had put those in there earlier, because I was not expecting phones to render at 330px. But they do, a 150px padding on both left and right is obviously too much. It squished my Bootstrap columns, so I replaced the 150px padding with a 10% padding.

That solved most of my problems. After that, there were a couple of elements left that were too wide for 330px. I solved this problem by adding a few media screen clauses to my css, that make certain elements smaller below 400px width.

The page now looks fine at 330px wide. Even on a physical smartphone.